Where is the best place to cut and rebuild my bathroom drain pipe?
I am remodeling my bathroom.  I'm at the point of fitting the drain in.
They glued all the PVC together up to the ABS.  Where would be a good place to cut? I've marked in the photo where I am thinking, but before I do it I was hoping to get some advice.
Once I make that cut, then I'll find the pieces I need to build back this structure they originally put in here.


With knowing only that you want to cut, then attach something new, your position of cut along the bottom of the elbow is correct.
Of course leave as much pipe as possible and you are on track.

I agree, assuming you don't want to replace the trap for any reason. Be sure to buff away the cement from the PVC before attempting a new cement weld.

Great thanks both.  I would replace all of it if that was a better approach.  It just seems cutting there and then building it back up to the floor under the tub will work.
